# mysqli_connect() error in laravel , minor version error

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I use `mysqli_connect()` in `laravel 5.8` and get me this error:

> Headers and client library minor version  mismatch. Headers:50560 Library:50637

My code is :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(MY_DB_HOST, MY_DB_USER, MY_DB_PASS) ;
```

Comment: Where is this code: `$conn = mysqli_connect(MY_DB_HOST, MY_DB_USER, MY_DB_PASS) ;`?

Comment: @Rehmat In  a controller

Comment: Laravel already comes with database abstraction libraries. i.e. Eloquent. You shouldn't be using custom code. Is there any particular reason why are you trying to create a connection manually?

Comment: @Rehmat When i using laravel connection give me error connection gone away and when use pdo or mysqli , I haven't error. when delete charset from connection in database in configs of laravel, problem solved but when using charset give error in laravel connection

Comment: I feel you should check your MySQL server and it's configuration. The issue should be in the infrastructure. You should be fixing that rather than modifying the code at Laravel's end.

Answer (score 1):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die("Oops some thing went wrong!!!!!!");
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks